# Influxdb query on tag returns nothing

Tags: influxdb

I have an Influxdb with lots of fields and a single tag:

```
> show tag keys
name: rtl433
tagKey
------
model
```

Now, I want a list of all possible values for model, so I run

```
SELECT model FROM rtl433
>
```

-and it returns nothing. Why? There's lots of data in model if I select *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use classic SQL solution, but InfluxDB is not classic SQL DB. You should check [InfluxDB doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-schema/#show-tag-values) and you will find solution:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "model"
```

Comment: This worked - thanks! I can see that InfluxDB is quite different from classic SQL. Thanks for the reference!